# Shortcut to and/or avoiding the "self" reference to a method within other methods of the same class

Tags: python

Consider a trivial `print` helper method - that has the intention to reduce typing / clutter for a specifically formatted output structure:

```
class MyClass(object):

  def p(self, msg,o=None):
    import datetime
    omsg = ": %s" %repr(o) if o is not None else ""
    print("[%s] %s%s\n" %(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0], msg, omsg))
```

The point of making it short/sweet was *not* to then type

```
  self.p('Hello world')
```

But is that the only option?

Note: I want to distribute this class within a small team - and not add a `function` `p()` to their namespaces.

Comment: There seems to be no reason this `p` method needs to be one - it might as well be a function. In that sense, yes, it is possible.

Comment: You could do `point = self.point` in the scope wherever you're using `self.point`. But honestly, I don't think `self` is that much more to type.

Comment: You should have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/136097/7051394. Besides, the title of your question is a bit misleading: "avoiding the `self` reference" feels like you want to omit `self` as you would omit `this` in Java or most OOP languages, which is not possible in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `self` anywhere in the method you can decorate it with `@staticmethod` and omit the `self` arg

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod

```
class MyClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def p(msg, o=None):
        import datetime
        omsg = ": %s" %repr(o) if o is not None else ""
        print("[%s] %s%s\n" %(str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0], msg, omsg))
```

You can still call it via `self.p(...)` from within other methods on instances of the class

You can also call it directly from `MyClass.p(...)`

Comment: This is along the lines of precisely what I want. Intellij is still complaining about the reference to `p`: but will try it in python repl.

Comment: yes this works! thx! Though `intellij` (/`pycharm`) parser gets confused.